# Generic Method to Invoke button on press Enter key

Tags: jquery, html

Is there any way to invoke "search" button on "Enter" key press event through jquery.

I have many number of screens and each screen have "Search" button with different id and name.

Comment: Give every search button a common class, catch the enter key as it bubbles up to the body, find the element by class, and trigger click.  Other than that, this question is too broad.

Comment: Thanks, I got direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one, I have Given each button for a common class

```
$(function() {
$('form').each(function() {
var form = this;   
 $(this).find('input').keypress(function(e) {
        // Enter pressed?
        if(e.which == 10 || e.which == 13) {
             form.find('input[class*="search"]').click();

     }
    });

    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, Its working for me.

Comment: `'input[class*="search"]'` is too generic since it could match `.bar-searchFoo` aswell. If you use i.e. a CSS SUIT naming convention, a `.Form-search` as selector would be best.

Comment: Also I think you wanted to suggest `var form = $(this);` instead? Here's also a naming convention for *jQuery element* variables, and that's `$form`

Comment: Also, the `.each` on `$('form')` is not needed. You can go directly like: `$(".Form").find('.Form-query').on("keypress", function() {` without the wrapping each function. Than inside you could simply `$(this).find(".Form-search")`